# Camera rotation over the object

Tags: camera, path

I have a camera tracking an empty object on a path and when the camera above the empty its rotating. Is there an option to lock the camera?

[image]

[image: Camera constraint]

Comment: Could you maybe post a screenshot of your object constraint on the camera

Answer (score 4):

If you want to lock the camera in such a way that it's upside down when it reaches the end of the curve:

[image]

you can use a Damped Track constraint.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this setup (with same constraints order, same X, Y, Z settings).
Took me some fidgeting but it works for me.

[EDIT]
You can keep Space as both World Space, it works the same.

[image]

Comment: Can you explain the settings for Local Space and World Space?

Comment: I wish I could :). I had not even noticed I'd left them that way. It works without it.